# Backend and Frontend Database

Tags: database, frontend, backend

I'm just wondering what software would be best to create a database to be used on a network with both macs and pcs. I have to create a back end database to be set up on a central machine. A front end database will be used throughout the office by everyone to access customer records etc. Does anyone know any good tutorials about database splitting as well?

Comment: Have you considered building a web application?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a standard web application, which provides a lot of plugins for managing your database (with an ORM). Ruby on Rails and Python/Django spring to mind. Database splitting is not a good idea (look up database consistency, atomic operations, ...)